# send email via Magento

Tags: email, magento

I've seen on a few blog articles that this is a common way to send an email in Magento, but I have for the life of me, no idea why this email isnt being sent in 1.10!  This is my method:

```
protected function _emailCode($code, $invoice) {

    $order = $invoice->getOrder();
    // Transactional Email Template's ID
    $templateId = 1;

    // Set sender information
    $senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name');
    $senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email');
    $sender = array('name' => $senderName,
                'email' => $senderEmail);

    // Set recepient information
    $recepientEmail = $order->getCustomerEmail();
    $recepientName = $order->getCustomerName();     

    // Get Store ID
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

    // Set variables that can be used in email template
    $vars = array('voucherCode' => $code);

    $translate  = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');

    // Send Transactional Email
    Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
        ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars, $storeId);

    $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
}
```

I should note that emails works in other parts of Magento so sendmail is working properly and all that, also all my variables here are defined correctly and not empty when going through this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that transactional email with ID=1 exist?
try setting `$templateId='sales_email_order_template'`
this is a default template, should fit working script.
Check exception.log also.

Comment: thanks.. ill give that a shot.  yes, 1 does exist.  give me a few hours to give this a go.